# How to draw data properties aside a graph node?

Tags: d3.js

I'm drawing a graph with D3 in which the node is a picture with name above. I would now like display some properties on the right side of the node.

```
var node = svg.select(".nodes").selectAll(".node")
    .data(nodes, function(d) {return d.id});
var nodeEnter = node.enter()
    .append("g")
    .attr("class", function(d) { return "node "+d.type})
    .attr("id", function(d) { return d.label })
    .call(force.drag);
nodeEnter.filter(function(d) {return (d.properties)}).append("rect")
    .attr("x", -40)
    .attr("y", -50)
    .attr("width", 130)
    .attr("height", 90);

nodeEnter.filter(function(d) {return (d.imgB64)}).append("image")
    .attr("xlink:href", function(d) { return 'data:image/png;base64, ' + d.imgB64; })
    .attr("x", -40)
    .attr("y", -40)
    .attr("width", 80)
    .attr("height", 80);

d3.selectAll(node);
var textNode = nodeEnter.filter(function(d) { return (d.imgB64) && (d.name));
textNode.append("text")
    .attr("class", function(d) { return "text "+d.type; })
    .attr("text-anchor", function(d) { return (d.properties) ? "left" : "middle"})
    .attr("dx", -38)
    .attr("dy", function(d) { return (d.properties) ? -38 : 42})
    .text(function(d) {
        return d.name;
    });
var textNode = nodeEnter.filter(function(d) { return (d.properties)});
textNode.append("text")
    .attr("text-anchor", "left")
    .attr("dx", 40)
    .attr("dy", -30)
    .style("font-size",9)
    .text(function(d) { return "MW: "+d.properties.MW.toPrecision(3); });
```

The above code properly draw one property on the right side of the image. How could I loop through all available properties of each node and display them as a list.

Each node data is formatted as follow:
{imgB64: "...", name: "A", properties: {MW: 354, logP: 4.6, pKd: -6.2, logPapp: -5.99}}

I tried the following:

```
var textNode = nodeEnter.filter(function(d) { return (d.properties)});
textNode.append("text")
    .data(function(d) { return d.properties })
    .attr("text-anchor", "left")
    .attr("dx", 40)
    .attr("dy", function(d,i) { return (i*15-30) })
    .style("font-size",9)
    .text(function(d) { return "foo" });
```

I get the an error message "TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'd.properties')". 
How should I create new data to handle the properties?

Code is shared on [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pducrot/hddye6ng) 
Thanks

Comment: get a fiddle together and we can show you

Comment: And I don't think `.data(function(d) { return d.properties })` is a valid data input. `.data` expects an array as its first input which should be like `.data(nodes)` in this case. Then you can choose the properties.

Comment: I'll try to get a fiddle. However extracting the code is quite complex. Getting data an array is probably right think to do first. Thanks.

Comment: I managed to create a fiddle (http://jsfiddle.net/pducrot/hddye6ng). The current code shows what I'm expecting, the commented code doesn't work. As mentioned by echonax, d.properties should probably by transformed into an array.

Comment: Indeed, d.properties doesn't is not a valid input, it's not an array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested by echonax, d.properties was not an array. This can be addressed by

```
.data(function(d) { return jsonToArray(d.data) })
```

with

```
function jsonToArray(data) {
    var a = [];
    for (k in data) {
        a.push({key: k, value: data[k]});
    }
    return a;
}
```

Thanks to echonax suggestion, I saved a lot if redundant code.